# Smallest normal subgroup making quotient abelian, nilpotent, solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Given a finite group $G$ that is *not* abelian, nilpotent, or solvable, what is the smallest normal subgroup $H$ in each case such that $G/H$ is abelian, nilpotent, or solvable (respectively)?

In the abelian case it seems clear that the correct subgroup is the commutator subgroup. But what of the other two? Perhaps I'm just shaky with the concepts (of nilpotency and solvability) but I'm having trouble finding the right way to tackle this problem.

Edit: Well I've tried the most obvious thing and it worked out.

For the nilpotent case I took the intersection of all the subgroups in the lower central series, and for the solvable case I took the intersection of all subgroups in the derived/commutator series.

Comment: In many cases the answer's trivial: if $\;G\;$ is simple non-abelian then the minimal normal such sbgp. is $\;G\;$ , of course. Pretty boring.

Comment: In many cases it isn't, though. One gets some very different smallest normal subgroups of $D_{2n}$ making the quotient nilpotent, depending on the order of $n$.

Comment: Your answers are correct when $G$ is finite. When $G$ is infinite, it could happen that the lower central series and/or the derived series are non-terminating (this happens in noncyclic free groups, for example), in which case there is no smallest normal subgroup with the required property. For fixed $k>0$, there is always a smallest normal subgroup such that the quotient is nilpotent of class at most $k$ or solvable with derived length at most $k$.

Answer (score 2):

The things you are asking about are quite well studied:

Suppose $G$ is a group and $\mathfrak{U}$ is a variety of groups (a class of groups, that is closed under taking subgroups, quotients and direct products; examples of varieties include abelian groups, nilpotent groups of class less than $c$ for any constant $c$ and soluble groups of class less than $c$ for any constant $c$). Then the smallest normal subgroup $H$ of $G$, such that $\frac{G}{H} \in \mathfrak{U}$ is called verbal. Basic properties of verbal subgroups can be seen [under this link](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Verbal_subgroup)

What's about the classes of all nilpotent (soluble) groups, then this does not work (because they are not varieties). However, we can look at the intersection of all verbal subgroups corresponding to the varieties of nilpotent (soluble) groups of class less than $c$ for all possible constants $c$. This subgroup will be normal and there are two cases possible:

1) Quotient by it is nilpotent (soluble). Then it is the subgroup you are looking for.

2) Quotient by it is non-nilpotent (non-soluble). Then the subgroup you were looking for does not exist.

Comment: However, "all nilpotent groups" and "all solvable groups" are not varieties, so this does not solve the question "quotient is nilpotent" or "quotient is solvable".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I edited my answer to cover this too.